# The fastest way of finding the largest palindromic substring of a string

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm using Python to find the largest palindromic substring of a given string

For instance if our string is 'ABCBCD' the program should print 3

And if the output is 'ABC' it just prints 0

I've writen a code that I think works perfectly.

But I want to know if it is well optimized.

Here is my code :

```
def IsPalindrom(s):
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        if s[i]!=s[len(s)-i-1]:
            return False
    return True

s=input("Enter a string:")
n=len(s)
maximum=0
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        t=s[i:j+1]
        m=len(t)
        if (IsPalindrom(t) and m>maximum):
            maximum=m
if maximum==1:
    maximum=0
print(maximum)
```

I was also planing to add a condition

```
if maximum>m:
    continue
```

But I'm not sure if it's good or not

Please consider the time and memory complexity when giving a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Most efficient? No, your solution is close O(n^3). The most efficient way to solve this problem is using Manacher's Algorithm for an O(n) solution, detailed here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring#Manacher's_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring#Manacher%27s_algorithm).